# What's the best practice for testing a github pull request?

Tags: testing, github, pull-request

Github pull requests are a great way of receiving code contributions to open source projects, but what's the best way to pull them into your code base?

A developer might say they've got all the tests passing on their fork of the code, and a review of their code looks good; but if you just merge and then your local tests fail you've got your repo in a bit of a state.

Is there some good way of running all the project tests on the code that you would get, if you accepted the pull request, without actually accepting it?

Comment: Just check out their commit first, and make sure the tests pass.

Comment: Also, if you have your tests automated through [Travis](http://travis-ci.org), I believe they will be run over the pull-request automatically. Which is nifty.

Comment: Meager - sounds good, but I'm not so worried about whether their repo tests pass as I am about whether the merged result will pass, but I can check that out all locally via cherrypicking and test the merge locally?  Is that the best practise?

Comment: Chowlett: wow Travis sounds cool - will have to check that out - thanks!

Comment: We've added Travis to our project http://github.com/tansaku/LocalSupport - appears to be working like a charm - I assume it tests the results of the pull request merge rather than the repo the pull is coming from?  Either way, if you answer the question I could flag you as correct ...